# hack safe authentication information database storage

Tags: php, security, passwords

In light of how many major websites have been hacked and their databases of password decrypted what is the best way to secure authentication?

Basically I am interested in a way to secure access to a part of a site to members in a way that if hacked would under no circumstances let hackers get a hold of the user's passwords.

Nothing is invulnerable but at least make it very difficult to crack.

Comment: Hash and salt your passwords. Use bcrypt.

Comment: Better fit for http://security.stackexchange.com/ I'd say.

Comment: May I ask why did you give me -1 to who ever did?

Comment: The only "guaranteed security" is keep your server off the Internet - or *any* network - lock it in a closet, and make sure no human can touch it :)

Comment: @paulsm4 very funny.. not what I am looking for though

Answer (score 5):

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

### Use `bcrypt`

Use [bcrypt](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos.html).
Use [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby).
Use [bcrypt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt/).
Use [bcrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx).
Use [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).
Use [bcrypt](http://p3rl.org/Authen::Passphrase::BlowfishCrypt).
Use [bcrypt](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/).
Use [bcrypt](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).
Use [bcrypt](https://github.com/smarkets/erlang-bcrypt).

### Why Not {`MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA256`, `SHA512`, `SHA-3`, etc}?

These are all *general purpose* hash functions, designed to calculate a digest
of huge amounts of data in as short a time as possible. This means that they are
fantastic for ensuring the integrity of data and utterly rubbish for storing
passwords.

A modern server can calculate the MD5 hash of about
[330MB every second](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks-amd64.html). If your
users have passwords which are lowercase, alphanumeric, and 6 characters long,
you can try *every single possible password of that size* in around
**40 seconds**.

And that’s without investing anything.

If you’re willing to spend about 2,000 USD and a week or two picking up
[CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html), you can put together your
own little supercomputer cluster which will let you
[try around 700,000,000 passwords a second](http://www.win.tue.nl/cccc/sha-1-challenge.html).
And that rate you’ll be cracking those passwords at the rate of more than **one
per second.**

### Salts Will Not Help You

It’s important to note that **salts are useless for preventing dictionary
attacks or brute force attacks.** You can use huge salts or many salts or
hand-harvested, shade-grown, organic [Himalayan pink salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayan_salt).
It doesn’t affect how fast an attacker can try a candidate password, given the
hash and the salt from your database.

Salt or no, if you’re using a general-purpose hash function designed for speed
you’re well and truly effed.

### `bcrypt` Solves These Problems

How? Basically, it’s slow as hell. It uses a variant of the Blowfish
encryption algorithm’s keying schedule, and introduces a *work factor*, which
allows you to determine how expensive the hash function will be. Because of
this, `bcrypt` can keep up with Moore’s law. As computers get faster you can
increase the work factor and the hash will get slower.

How much slower is `bcrypt` than, say, `MD5`? Depends on the work factor. Using
a work factor of 12, `bcrypt` hashes the password `yaaa` in about 0.3 seconds on
my laptop. `MD5`, on the other hand, takes less than a microsecond.

So we’re talking about **5 or so orders of magnitude**. Instead of cracking a
password every 40 seconds, I’d be cracking them every **12 years** or so. Your
passwords might not need that kind of security and you might need a faster
comparison algorithm, but `bcrypt` allows you to choose your balance of speed
and security. Use it.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you. Got any clever idea that does not take forever?

Comment: `bcrypt` is the way to go and doesn't "take forever" when it comes down to a real server.

Answer (score 0):

Besides proper password handling (like bcrypt, as already mentioned), you need to do the password hashing on a dedicated device/machine.

This "device" for password hashing is a separate system which contains so called "local parameter", which is an extra input to the hash function (say, 128-bit strong random number). This local parameter must be unreadable by the host system (your app, which does the user authentication).

Using such a dedicated machine for password hashing buys you an extra layer of security if your password database/app gets compromised.

Comment: So called 'peppering' is technically not *much* more secure. It would be better to AES the hash using a secret key: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html

Comment: No need to AES. If one is implementing dedicated system for password hashing, it is good to go with one-way hashing. See my comment on the article you linked (the first comment). It is all about layered protection. Also, see http://www.openwall.com/presentations/PHDays2012-Password-Security/mgp00049.html and http://www.openwall.com/presentations/PHDays2012-Password-Security/mgp00050.html